# Puppet unable to add user to AD group

Tags: puppet, dsc

I'm trying to add user to group on my DC using puppet:

```
 dsc_xgroup {'DomainAdministrators':

            dsc_ensure    => 'present',
            dsc_memberstoinclude => 'tfl@ad.contoso.com',
            dsc_groupname   => 'test',
            dsc_credential => {
            'user' => 'Administrator@ad.contoso.com',
            'password' => 'Passw0rd01'
            },
            }
```

Group is created, but unable to add user to it:

Error: PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_xGroupResource  failed to execute Set-

```
TargetResource functionality with error message: Exception calling "Save" with "0" argument(s): "An unknown directory user object was requested
"
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[windows.example.com]/Dsc_xgroup[DomainAdministrators]/ensure: change from 'absent' to 'present' failed: PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_xGroupResource  failed to execute Set-TargetResource functionality with error message: Exception calling "Save" with "0" argument(s): "An unknown directory user object was requested
```

Answer (score -2):

Try rebooting windows server, i had similar issue and reboot solved it.